# Confidence interval for measured value with error

Tags: confidence-interval, error

I have the (inexact) measurement of N points. I also have access to the true value for M < N of such points.

Suppose the measurement error is normally distributed.

Based on this knowledge I could probably compute the mean ("error_mean") and SD ("error_sd") of the measurement error based on the M points for which I have both the true value and the measurement. However I am not sure how to do this. See below what I need exactly.

My objective is: considering one of the N-M points for which I do not have access to the true value, I want to give a 95% confidence interval for such value.

I think that the confidence interval should be something around:

```
CI_lower_end = measurement -error_mean -2*error_sd
CI_upper_end = measurement -error_mean +2*error_sd
```

However I suspect that error_mean and error_sd are not simply the mean and SD of the M values that result from performing "measurement - true_value" of the M points above. In particular, if M is low such as 2, the error_sd would probably be much underestimated with such naive approach.

Can you tell me how to compute the abovementioned confidence interval? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question, you have to determine the relationship between the ground truth and the measured values - in other words, you need a "calibration" of your measurement system. This is what your M points are for, I suppose. There are several possibilities:

1. data has a good linear fit passing through zero, with a slope of 1. This would be indicative of a well calibrated system
2. As above, but slope is not 1: you have a gain error
3. As (1) but the intercept is not 1: you have an offset error
4. Your measured data has curvature: your system is nonlinear
5. The relationship cannot be confidently determined from your data: you have a bad measurement system

The reason that I dwell on this is that it informs what you do next. In cases 1-3 you can create a simple fit through the data points (x = true value, y = measured value), then compute the confidence interval for points outside that range: this gives you an estimate for the confidence interval for the other points. Just to be a little bit tricky - since you have the measured value, in order to get the confidence interval from that measurement (y), you would want to

1. Plot the measurement on the Y axis
2. Extend a horizontal line from there to the calibration curve
3. At the corresponding value of X ("true value"), read left-to-right to find the uncertainty in the underlying true value.

In case 4, making any statistical inferences about your measurement system is really meaningless: you should fix your measurement system first...

Do you know how to make a fit with confidence intervals?

**EDIT** now that you have clarified your need and intention, here is a more specific answer. I will leave the above for future visitors (who may have a different need).

I will treat two cases. One is the one you said you have: you have a well calibrated system, and $M<N$ noisy values for which you claim to know the "exact" value - but for which the measurement contains some additional Gaussian white noise (AWGN). If that is true, then you just need to estimate the noise in the measurement system (assumed to be independent of the measured value) and you're done. You would estimate the error (given that you know the mean) with

$$\sigma = \sqrt{\sum\frac{(x_i-x_k)^2}{n}}$$

where $x_i$ is the measurement and $x_k$ is the "known" value. I used $n$ instead of $(n-1)$ since you claim the exact value is known - so we are not giving up a degree of freedom by computing the mean from the measured values (note this is unusual...)

Note that you have some uncertainty associated with this measurement of $\sigma$ since you only used $M$ samples to compute it. This will come back in the next equation...

The 95% confidence interval for a specific value is now given by

$\pm t(0.025, M) \sigma $

(NOTE - this value $t$ is considerably larger than 2 for small values of M - this confirms your suspicion that your simple formula would not be sufficient). In this formulat we are assuming a constant value for $\sigma$ as computed above (constant = independent of the value of x).

Usually you get t from a table; but you want this "in C and fast". Here is an approach.

The t value you want can be taken from a table for small values of M:

```
M    t
1   12.706
2   4.303
3   3.182
4   2.776
5   2.571
6   2.447
7   2.365
8   2.306
9   2.262
10  2.228
```

As M gets larger, this value will approach `1.960` - the critical value for the 95% confidence interval of the normal distribution (a bit like the `2` you were using in your simple expression). A reasonable *approximation* in the range $10<M<\infty $ is (I derived this by solving for the coefficients):

```
t = 1.960 + 2.365477926/M + 3.08054547/(M^2)
```

This agrees with the tabulated values to better than 0.001 - should be close enough for a confidence interval calculation (see implementation in C in code below)

**Second method**
If you do NOT know the absolute truth about your M points (this is NOT your situation, but one that visitors to this page might reasonable encounter), then you can generate a *calibration curve* from these points; from this you can compute the uncertainty in other values. It will give rise to a slightly wider confidence interval (because you injected less information).

The assumption is a well behaved system; we have a calibration curve with *at least* 3 points (with fewer than 3 points you cannot estimate both the offset, slope, and noise). The calculations needed can be found at http://people.stfx.ca/bliengme/ExcelTips/RegressionAnalysisConfidence3.htm . Repeating the main points here:

1. Compute the straight line fit through the calibration points
2. Compute the value $x$ corresponding to the measured $y$ from the straight line (this is $$x=(y-b)/a$$ for the usual notation of the fitted line $$y = ax + b$$
3. Confidence interval is given by

$$\pm t(0.025, M-2)\frac{S_{xy}}{a}\sqrt{\frac{1}{M}+1+\frac{(x-x_{av,M})^2}{SS_{x,M}}}$$

where

$x_{av,M}$ is the mean X ('true') value of the M calibration measurements, and 
$SS_{x,M}$ is $\sum{(x-x_{av,M}}$ taken over the M calibration measurements.

Translating all the above to C code, for an example data set with 5 "known" values (example taken from spreadsheet at link above - and results match to 3 sf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double tcrit95(int df) {
  static double tsmall[]= {12.706, 4.303, 3.182, 2.776, 2.571, 2.447, 2.365, 2.306, 2.262, 2.228};
  if(df < 1) return -1;
  if(df <= 10) return tsmall[df-1];
  return 1.960 + (2.365477926 + 3.08054547/df)/df;
}

double steyx(double *x, double *y, int n) {
// standard error of predicted y
double mx, my, sx, sy;
int ii;
for(ii=0; ii<n; ii++) {
  sx += x[ii]; sy += y[ii];
}
mx = sx / n; my = sy / n;
double s1=0, s2=0, s3=0;
for(ii=0; ii<n; ii++) {
  s1 += (y[ii]-my)*(y[ii]-my);
  s2 += (x[ii]-mx)*(y[ii]-my);
  s3 += (x[ii]-mx)*(x[ii]-mx);
}
return sqrt((s1 - s2*s2/s3)/(n-2));
}

int main(void) {
  double calX[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  double calY[]= {2.86, 5.20, 7.40, 9.60, 12.10};
  double a, b, sx=0, sy=0, sxx=0, sxy=0, avx, avy;
  int ii, n=5, df;

  df = n - 2; // fitting straight line: lose two df

  // compute straight line:
  for(ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    sx += calX[ii];
    sxx += calX[ii]*calX[ii];
    sy += calY[ii];
    sxy += calX[ii] * calY[ii];
  }
  avx = sx / n;
  b = (sy*sxx - sxy*sx) / (n*sxx - sx * sx);
  printf("The intercept is %.3f\n", b);
  a = (sy - n*b) / sx;
  printf("The slope is %.3f\n", a);

  // now compute confidence interval for a point Y that was measured: say Y = 6.55
  double t95, clim, Y=6.55, compx;
  t95 = tcrit95(df);
  compx = (Y - b) / a;
  clim = t95 * steyx(calX, calY, n) / fabs(a) * sqrt(1.0/n + 1 + (compx - avx)*(compx - avx)/sxx);
  printf("95% confidence interval goes from %.3f to %.3f\n", compx - clim, compx + clim);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I know how to use R to compute the confidence interval after a linear fit, however in this case I need to do that in C++ and very quickly. I think I can remove offset, gain and nonlinearity a-priori (based on an offline fit), however still an AWGN for each point will be present and it's standard deviation is unknown at compile time (different at each run, and in each run I have the M "calibration" points that can be used for that). Can you answer my question under the assumption of AWGN for each point, no bias, no gain, and no use of R? Thank you

Comment: If you are not in a rush... I am traveling right now and answering in detail on a phone is a recipe for disaster... Will come up with an answer once I return to civilization (well I am at the birthplace of Hippocrates - so in a sense surrounded by millennia of civilization).